# Why is "Driver not found: [org.postgresql.Driver]" with postgresql 9.3-1102.jdbc41 dependency declared?

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework

I'm working with JDK 1.7 (Eclipse) and downloaded version '9.3-1102 JDBC 41' and added the 'postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar' file to the 'Referenced Libaries'.

Here's my 'build.sbt' file dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1102.jdbc41"
)
```

and added the following to 'application.conf':

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
db.default.user="postgres"
db.default.password="postgre"
```

Still, I get 'Driver not found: [org.postgresql.Driver]' due a class not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct value is

```
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1102-jdbc41"
```

Also you have to run `play update` inside your project after that (or if you are using Play 2.3, `activator update`) so the required dependencies are downloaded.

Comment: I got unresolved depency for 'org.postgresql#postgresql;9.3-1102.jdbc41'but I found this: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.postgresql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22postgresql%22 . Is this what I'm looking for to resolve this dependency? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: You need to change that string. It isn't `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1102.jdbc41"` but `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1102-jdbc41"`

Comment: Yes, I did that, just realised I forgot to 'reload' then 'update'. It works now.